# Relocating from India to Las Vegas on L2 visa

Tags: usa, relocation, l1-visa

I am relocating to Las Vegas from India with my husband. What will I need to do to get an Employment Authorization? I am a post graduate in Psychology from India.

Comment: You need to apply for an [EAD using the I-765 form](http://www.uscis.gov/i-765).

Answer (score 1):

> [USCIS I-765, Application for Employment Authorization](https://www.uscis.gov/i-765)
>
> Certain foreign nationals, who are eligible to work in the United States, use [Form I-765](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-765.pdf?download=1) to request an employment authorization document (EAD).
>
> The filing fee for Form I-765 is $410. You must also pay an $85 biometric services fee, for a total of $495, if you are:
>
> - Requesting consideration of Deferred Action for Childhood Arrivals (DACA);
>     A -  beneficiary of an approved employment-based immigrant petition and you are facing compelling circumstances; or
> - A spouse or unmarried dependent child of a beneficiary of an employment-based immigrant petition who is facing compelling circumstances.
>
> There is no biometric services fee for any other eligibility category.
>
> Some individuals may be exempt from paying fees. See the form instructions for more information.
>
> [Instructions for Form I-765 (PDF, 332 KB)](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-765instr.pdf?download=1)